# Grails 2.4.0: Upgrade script still missing

Tags: grails

With respect to this topic:
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-2-4-RC1-Script-Upgrade-not-found-td4656743.html

How would one manually upgrade, willing to play with cutting-edge?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow the steps in the official manual http://grails.org/doc/2.4.0/guide/upgradingFrom23.html

> The upgrade command has been removed from Grails 2.4. The procedure for upgrading to the latest version of Grails will be detailed in the user guide from now on. Below are steps that must be taken to upgrade an application from 2.3.x to 2.4.

and

> The set-grails-version command should be run to update the application's metadata to indicate which version of Grails the application is built with.

Answer (score 5):

The `upgrade` script has been replaced by a more appropriately name command called `set-grails-version`. Since an upgrade is not something we can automate easily the name of this command provided problematic for people's expectations.

If you have a Grails application that is missing some files you can also run `grails init` which will populate any required missing files.